# jTextField update in real time based on other jTextFields values?

Tags: java, jtextfield

I have a quick question to ask.

The problem is that I need a jTextField to update its values according to a users input in other 3 other jTextFields.
One txtfield is "idQuarto" which basically is how I know the price of the room.
The other txtfields are Dates (Checkin & Checkout), I calculate the days between them.

This is where I need help, the textfield (Total) is where I want it to update based on the users input of dates and room id. (Price of ID Quarto * Days).

Here is a picture of the program: http://gyazo.com/a7e47227a0be9f5720c005e61a1951d9

Hope everybody understands what I mean.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> This is where I need help, the textfield (Total) is where I want it to update based on the users input of dates and room id. (Price of ID Quarto * Days).

`FocusListener` will fire whenever focus is lost or gained that is better than `KeyListener`.

```
FocusAdapter updateTotalFocusAdapter = new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
         totalTextField.setText([Price of ID Quarto * Days]);
    }
};

checkInDateTextField.addFocusListener(updateTotalFocusAdapter);
checkOutDateTextField.addFocusListener(updateTotalFocusAdapter);
idQuartoTextField.addFocusListener(updateTotalFocusAdapter);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a `keyAdapter` to your textFields that sends a message to your update method like so

`A = new JTextField();
 A.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
       updateField();
    }
});`

any time a key is typed into the text field with the Adapter, in this case, it will call the updateField() method.

Comment: -1, don't use a KeyListener. When using Swing you can use a `DocumentListener`. A DocumentListener is a higher level API and should be used over low level API's when available. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information. Also, you suggestion will not work anyway because the Document has not yet been updated when the keyPressed() method is invoked.